# Recent comments on author page?

Tags: custom-post-types, comments, author

I'm creating an author.php page and I'd like to show comments as well as posts from a custom post type. I already have the list of posts but I'm looking into an efficient way of displaying the most recent comments from that author as well. So far I haven't found anything except widget and bloated plugins.

I'd like to do that particularly in one stream (posts/comments) but I can understand if this is too challenging :)

Thanks!
Dennis

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to my attention, I'll make sure to mark my posts next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function calls all comments by an author and strips every comment to a max-length. Adjust the comment excerpt length when calling the function in your template like `wpse19316_author_comments( 100 );`.

```
function wpse19316_author_comments( $length )
{
    $final_length = (int) $length;
    $author_comments = get_comments( array( 'ID' => $GLOBALS['authordata']->ID ) );
    foreach ( $author_comments as $comment )
    {
        $comment_length = sublen( $comment->comment_content );
        $comment_excerpt = $comment->comment_content;
        if ( $comment_length > $final_length )
            $comment_excerpt = substr( $comment->comment_content, $final_length );
        echo $comment_excerpt.'<br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to get your function to work properly in our WP installation. I add the code above that you mentioned to the functions.php as cited below with standard php tags around it. And that tried to use <?php wpse19316_author_comments() ?> to display the output to an author page for a particular user on the author.php. Am I doing it right or is there something I'm missing? If you can help I would be so happy. Thanks in advance.