# Instead of 4 loops, how can I do it better?

Tags: query-posts

I want to grab all posts from an author under category X. Right now, I am using 4 separate loops to do this for 4 different categories. Is there a better way to do this? `query_posts`

Comment: Do you want to display the results separated per category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the category parameters of [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19316/recent-comments-on-author-page/19496#19496) answer, exchange `get_comments` with [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) and use the `include` argument to filter only the posts from the categories you need.